# Magento 2 Unable to change the Default Home page

Tags: magento2, home, domain

I am getting below error while changing the Default Home page from configuration on Magento Admin.

> Invalid domain name: The input does not match the expected structure
>   for a DNS hostname; The input does not appear to be a valid URI
>   hostname; The input does not appear to be a valid local network name

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to delete all your cookies? Which option do you want to change exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below-mentioned steps to set your default home page using Magento admin :

1. On the Admin panel, click Stores. In the Settings section, select Configuration.
2. Select Web under General in the panel on the left.
3. Open the Default Pages section, and continue with the following:
4. In the Default Web URL field, the default value cms or enter other value as needed.
5. In the CMS Home Page field, select the page you want to set as home page, as normal you should select “Home Page”
6. click Save Config.

I assure it will resolve your query.

Comment: Do you happen to know the path to look for in the database for the Default Web URL setting?

Comment: The Default Web URL field would be the module that would deal with the request. That said, cms is the default. If you access storeUrl.com/cms you'll see the default CMS page (configured in the next field).
Let's say you want the customer login page as your home page, so you would set Default Web URL field to "customer/account/login". 
If it's a category, you would set "catalog/category/view/id/20" for example.
I hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

@Abhinav Singh...your instructions do not work. My Default Web URL is cms and I have no idea what "other value as needed" means from your instruction. The default page is always CMS.
And in the CMS Home Page dropdown, it lists all the pages but it doesn't matter which one I choose from the dropdown, it does not take affect. It only show a the header and footer of my theme and the content section is blank with only "There was no Home CMS page configured or found. " written out.